# Safari odd behaviour

Tags: macos, mac, safari, catalina

I have some strange thing going on with my Safari browser. It only happens to Safari in address bar, no other text fields elsewhere does this. When I start typing word `best`, after I type `s` whole search bar gots cleared. It's really annoying and I don't know where can I find a fix for it. Tried clearing system settings, browser's and even with using another Mac user. Nothing helped. It's really a small thing but really a pain in the ass. Hope someone had this issue before because cannot really find anyone in the internet writing about it. 
Thanks!